# I am not able to pass query string parameter in Android+phonegap for android os 4

Tags: android, cordova

I am not able to pass query string parameter in Android+phonegap for android os 4
and i got this error

```
DroidGap: GapViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-1 Description=A network error occurred. URL=file:///android_asset/www/StoresInCity.html?name=NEW%20DELHI&category=store
```

Comment: looks like "A network error occurred"

Comment: quick googling gave: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

Answer (score 0):

What version of PhoneGap are you using? There is a known [Android OS bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535) that we are working around as of PhoneGap 2.1.